# Off topic questions: Stack recommendation

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a basic networking question that could be considered as off topic for this stack. Fair enough, I get that you're trying to run something that is more tailored to professionals here.

But can you recommend a stack for basic questions? I think that it could help a lot of people as well as many regulars of this stack, as many of the questions are flagged as off topic. "Server Fault" seems to be even further from what I'm looking for.

I'm not trying to waste anyone's time.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered [su]?

Comment: Both [networkengineering.se] and [sf] are for asking questions about business networks. [su] handles questions about personal networks. Each SE site has a [tour] and a [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, and you should always check with those for a site before posting on the site. There is also [metase] for questions about the SE sites.

Comment: Super User it is then. Cheers!